# Activity in android not starting as intended

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

The scenario I have consists of 3 activities:
1- Homepage
2-Login
3-Register
The thing is now Home page has 2 buttons one login and one for homepage , and the login activity should be called from either this button or from inside register after I am done registering ,also both login and register activities inflate 2 different fragments.

The problem : Login activity doesnt start , instead it sometimes just blinks with the layout it should inflate for a split second and then backs to the previous activity whichever one it is , also when I replaced the login activity with another activity it started normally with no problems

Any idea what that might be.

NOTE: I'm not getting any errors or so

Signin Activity code:

```
package engezni.Activties;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import Fragments.SigninFragment;
import engezni.Activties.R;

public class SignInScreen extends Activity {
FrameLayout frameLayout;
SigninFragment signinFragment;
TextView signinScreen;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_screen);

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    /*Setting text to the textview in the xml actionbar layout */
    signinScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbarTitleOrderScreen);
    signinScreen.setText("Sign In");
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar));
    getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backlogo));

    frameLayout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.signin_framelayout);
    signinFragment=new SigninFragment();
    if (findViewById(R.id.signin_framelayout) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        signinFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.signin_framelayout, signinFragment).commit();

    }



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sign_in_screen, menu);
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And then here is the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignInScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_in_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post the LoginActivity code so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: Post your manifest and LoginActivity

Comment: I have added both the signin activity and the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sign_in_screen, menu);
onBackPressed();
```

When the `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called that is where you go back to the last activity because you called `onBackPressed` which will destroy your current activity.

**solution:**

remove the `onBackPressed`